# Rails 4: Profile for users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Rails 4 app with a `User` model and it `has_one :client` where `Client` is the model where I store information about the client.  I want my users to be able to view a profile page with their client information but I'm not sure which action to use or how to route to it.

I want to be able to view a particular client using the show action:

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @client = @user.client
end
```

...but I also want a route for "my profile" which would rely on `current_user` and not finding a user by their ID.  In my mind this is also a show action and I'm trying to avoid adding custom methods and would rather find the "railsy" way to do this.

```
def show
    @user = current_user
    @client = @user.client
end
```

I know this is sorta philosophical, but if someone could explain the proper way to achieve this I would appreciate it.

Comment: well the rails way would be to create a ClientsController with a show method - you can remove any unnecessary actions such as index etc.... Or just create a show_client action in your users controller if its a one off action related to clients - nothing wrong with doing that. Best not to use UsersController#show as that would obfuscate it's intention - that would be expected to show a user.

Comment: totally agree, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I am not sure what you are trying to do. If you want to add a specific page about showing `current_user` profile. Why not adding a new `method`?

Like this

```
def profile
    @client = current_user.client
end
```

Or maybe you can validate the `params[:id]` in `show` action

Like this

```
def show
    @user = params[:id].present? ? User.find(params[:id]) : current_user
    @client = @user.client
end
```

Comment: I guess becasue my app has gotten kinda cluttered over time, I am trying to obey the Rails conventions and it was my understanding that sticking to the standard methods is the cleanest way, but perhaps a few extra methods is fine

Comment: If you really want to follow the Rails way, you can read this http://jeromedalbert.com/how-dhh-organizes-his-rails-controllers/